# Using IntStream to iterate and call a method

Tags: java, java-stream, fizzbuzz

How can I call a function to print a value while iterating over a range using an `IntStream`?

```
public static void fizzBuzz(int n) {

    // The below does not work as it expects a return value.
    // Is there a different method that I could use to perform this?
    IntStream.range(1, n).map(n -> print(n));
}

private static void print(int n){
    boolean isDivisibleBy3 = n % 3 == 0;
    boolean isDivisibleBy5 = n % 5 == 0;
    
    if(isDivisibleBy3 && isDivisibleBy5){
        System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (isDivisibleBy3){
        System.out.println("Fizz");
    } else if (isDivisibleBy5){
        System.out.println("Buzz");
    } else {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using map here? Use forEach

Comment: You can use `peek()` _to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline_ or use the `forEach()` operator to consume an each element from the stream (not return value compared to `map()`).

Comment: Sorry , map was just intended to show as an example - just wanted to understand if there is a functional interface that accepts a value could be used as part of foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you wanted.  Have the method return the string.  Then use `IntStream` to iterate thru the numbers.  These are then passed on to the method which maps an `int` to the returned value which is a `String`.  Then you simply print that value.

```
public class FizzBuzzStream {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int n = 20;
        
        IntStream.range(1, n).mapToObj(FizzBuzzStream::eval)
                .forEach(System.out::println); 
        
    }
    
    private static String eval(int n) {
        boolean isDivisibleBy3 = n % 3 == 0;
        boolean isDivisibleBy5 = n % 5 == 0;
        
        if (isDivisibleBy3 && isDivisibleBy5) {
            return "FizzBuzz";
        }
        if (isDivisibleBy3) {
            return "Fizz";
        }
        if (isDivisibleBy5) {
            return "Buzz";
        }
        return Integer.toString(n);
    }
    
}
```

Prints

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
Fizz
19
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map()` operation needs a non-void function as its input so this function can be applied to every element in your stream and replace them.
Use `forEach()` instead. It can apply a void function on your elements.

Also do not use `n` within your lambda expression. It is already declared and cannot be overwritten.

```
public static void fizzBuzz(int n) {
    IntStream.range(1, n).forEach(x -> print(x));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` is used when you want to convert one value to another. Since `print` doesn't return anything (its return type is `void`), you can't use `map`. You could use [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#forEach-java.util.function.IntConsumer-) instead though:

```
IntStream.range(1, n).forEach(n -> print(n));
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your current approach does not lend itself to `map` because your function is `void`. You **could** map `int` to `String` though. That method might look like,

```
private static String mapFizzBuzz(int n) {
    boolean isDivisibleBy3 = n % 3 == 0;
    boolean isDivisibleBy5 = n % 5 == 0;

    if (isDivisibleBy3 && isDivisibleBy5) {
        return "FizzBuzz";
    } else if (isDivisibleBy3) {
        return "Fizz";
    } else if (isDivisibleBy5) {
        return "Buzz";
    }
    return Integer.toString(n);
}
```

And then your current approach would work, if you further printed with a `forEach`. Like,

```
IntStream.range(1, n).mapToObj(x -> mapFizzBuzz(x)).forEach(System.out::println);
```